# How to redirect to my App after OAuth in Android PWA?

Tags: android, angular, oauth, progressive-web-apps

I’m generated a PWA with PWABuilder and Build an APK Bundle in Android Studio.
The OAuth flow (With Facebook and Google) works perfect in a Browser but don't in Native App.

The OAuth window open in a browser and don't redirect to my app.

The app is based on Angular 7. I’ve tried to force the OAuth window to open in a Webview but this don't redirect to the app then the OAuth window keeps in the app but don't close or redirect.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: did u get the answer?